# List item with big line height breaks anchor with a border-bottom

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, height, border

I'm bad with explaining my problems so I created an image:
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7aLw.png)

This is the codepen pen where I'm trying to recreate the effect and struggling for it to work:
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/ArnoldsK/pen/bpLrEj)

```
.nav > li {
    height: 90px;
    line-height: 90px;
}

.nav > li a {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

I know it can work like that because it works in page here, when hovering navigation links: hubfootwear(dot)com (sorry for this format, can't post more than 2 links)

I have experimented with element inspector for lots of minutes, yet I can't figure out why it works on that webpage but not on my codepen.

Comment: The link is 100% height of the `li` so naturally the bottom border is at the bottom of the `li`...where else would it be?

Comment: @Paulie_D yeah, but then how does it work in the example page?

Comment: The link isn't display:block I suspect...in fact on checking it's still the default of `display:inline`

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you man! It was so simple, I feel silly now. Haha.